# How to disassemble a system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls, disassembly

If I have the virtual address of system call, can I disassemble that system call? I want to do it on running kernel to find what all address are handled by the particular system call while running.

I am running 32 bit 2.6.38 kernel (x86).

Comment: I've read this a few times and I still can't figure out what you mean. What is the "address" of a system call?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz TO know whether a rootkit affected the system by looking at the disassembled instructions

Comment: What CPU ? "32 bit" isn't enough information

Comment: Looking at this and the answers and comments below, sounds like this might be better on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PaulR I am having corei3 running Debian Squeeze with custom linux kernel 2.6.38 (32 bit). I could easily get the system call virtual address (System.map file/ a kernel module). Can i disassmble the system call placed at that particular virtual address. I understood that GDB could do that by `gdb /boot/vmlinux-2.4.* /proc/kcore`. But in my Debian , I only have vmlinuz not vmlinux. Is there any other way?

Comment: OK - I have added edited your question to indicate that this is x86-specific and added an `x86` tag

Comment: @user567879: a good rootkit (especially one using virtualization) won't be directly visible in the affected system and will only be discovered indirectly by observing irregularities in timing, performance and maybe some glitches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you question is very meaningful.

Please read more about [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), [kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29), [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), and the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)

Essentially, a system call is (from the application point of view) an atomic operation implemented by one machine instruction (`int 0x80`, `syscall`, etc.) with a few book-keeping instructions before (e.g. loading the system call arguments to registers) and after (e.g. setting `errno`). When it happens, control goes into the kernel, with a (sort-of) different address space and a different [protection ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29); here is the [list of linux syscalls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls)

The real code doing the system call is inside the kernel. You can get the Linux kernel code on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)

See also the [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) and [asm.sourceforge.net](http://asm.sourceforge.net/)

To understand what system calls a given application or process is doing, use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear. I want to disassmble a particular system call for the running kernel so that I could find whether a rootkit attack occurred or not.

Comment: As I explained to you, that question has no meaning at all. The machine code for a system call is essentially one machine instruction (`syscall`) and you cannot "disassemble" it. Please take time to read all the links I gave you.

Comment: I understood that GDB could do that by gdb /boot/vmlinux-2.4.* /proc/kcore. But in my Debian , I only have vmlinuz not vmlinux. Is there any other way? This link gives the explanation http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/detecting-rootkits-and-kernel-level-compromises-linux

Comment: You understood wrongly. If you want to understand how system calls are implemented, study the Linux kernel. Its source code is free (GPLv2) and you are encouraged to study it. It is very complex, and several good books are explaining it. Indeed, if your kernel is compromized, your machine is zombie...

Comment: But the how could I get dump of assmebly code when I run `gdb /boot/vmlinux-2.4.* /proc/kcore (gdb) disass sys_read` using gdb?

Comment: Where are you looking: inside kernel space or inside user space... ??? (there is indeed some way to debug the kernel, and there have been progress about that). Most of the kernel code handling system calls is coded in C.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5841/discussion-between-user567879-and-basile-starynkevitch)