# Where is socket create function implemented in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I know the function to create socket:`int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);` is located in `#include <sys/socket.h>` and I can find it on my linux file system.

But where I can find the implementation of this function? I couldn't find a matching one in the [kernel source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/).

Comment: you want `socket()` function definition?

Comment: Why do you ask? With what point of view (kernel hacking, or user-land application code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/) for the authentic kernel source. Understand that [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) is one of the many [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (you need to understand precisely what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are) so it is implemented *inside the kernel* as `sys_socket` and/or `sys_socketcall` and/or `do_socket`; sockets and network code are an entire subsystem ([net/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/)) of the kernel, so see its [net/socket.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/socket.c), etc etc... See also [socketcall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketcall.2.html)

Application user-side code are simply issuing a syscall, so [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) is a thin wrapper around a system call (in [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) or whatever implementation of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) you are using). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501919/841108).

Comment: Also note that you’ll be calling a library function in `libc.so` that in turn calls the system call.

Comment: Yes, a wrapper function

Answer (score 2):

`sys/socket.h` should be in `/usr/include`. Typically, it's a part of the "GNU C Library", but depending on your system, that might also be a different C library (ie. on systems you can't call GNU/Linux, like Android, there might be different libc than glibc).

However, that's just the header, not the implementation of the syscalls beneath! You will have to look through glibc's source code (which usually is not installed, only the headers), and then match what you find there to the system calls implementation in linux.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the linux implementation of socket creation, you. can look [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c#L1357)